# codeignitor's anchor() method fails to hit method name specified in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to link this anchor to the method "newInvoice()" specified in controller

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url'); ?>
<li><?php echo anchor('new_invoice_c/newInvoice', 'New     Invoice'); ?></a> </li>
```

**controller**

```
class New_invoice_c extends CI_Controller {
    public function newInvoice()
    {
       $this->load->view('new_invoice');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `anchor()` is not returning the full string (when i check it via "view page source) but only upto first paraemeter i.e. method name as follows.

```
<a href="http://localhost/cibs/index.php/new_invoice_c">
```

When I renamed my mehtod to `index()` the view is loaded successfully.

It may seem naive but here is what i tried

```
echo anchor(site_url('new_invoice_c.php/newInvoice'), 'New Invoice');
echo anchor('new_invoice_c.php/newInvoice', 'New Invoice');
```

beside that I refresh the page after clearing chache but still I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<li><?php echo anchor('new_invoice_c/newInvoice', 'New     Invoice'); ?></a> </li>
```

to

```
<li><?php echo anchor('new_invoice_c/newinvoice', 'New Invoice'); ?></li>
```

You added `</a>` where it was not required

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<?php echo anchor('new_invoice_c/newinvoice', 'New Invoice');?>
```

Here is official Codeigniter user guide, check it. 
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

change it

`echo anchor(site_url('new_invoice_c.php/newInvoice'), 'New Invoice');`

to

`echo anchor(base_url('new_invoice_c.php/newInvoice'), 'New Invoice');`

Comment: I copy and pasted you code but still can't getting desired result

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a silly mistake while doing all this. I was editing the other file while accessing the anchor from another file. Every thing was ok except the source file. any how, thanks to all for answering `<li><?php echo anchor('new_invoice_c', 'New Invoice') ?> </li>`